# Reading list of statements and ending with a single expression, when statements can be expressions

Tags: haskell, parsec

I've run into a problem where I want to parse a block of code with the following syntax

```
{
    <stmt>;
    <stmt>;
    <stmt>;
    <expr>
}
```

A statement can be of the form `<expr>;`. This trips up Parsec in a way which I don't know how to fix. This is probably just me being kinda new to Haskell and the Parsec library, but I don't know where to search for a solution to the problem. I've written an example that captures my exact problem.

With the input `{ 5; 5; 5 }` it fails on the third `5`, because it expects there to be a `;` present. How do I get around this?

```
import           Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import           Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Combinator

parseIdentifier = do
    first <- letter
    rest  <- many $ letter <|> digit <|> char '_'
    return $ first : rest

parseExpr = parseIdentifier <|> many1 digit


parseStmt = parseExpr <* char ';'

parseBlock = between
    (char '{' >> spaces)
    (spaces >> char '}')
    (do
        stmts <- try $ parseStmt `sepBy` spaces
        parseExpr
    )

readParser :: Parser String -> String -> String
readParser parser input = case parse parser "dusk" input of
    Left  err -> show err
    Right val -> val

main = interact $ readParser parseBlock
```

Comment: You can us `<*` instead of custom `>==`. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42-

Comment: Is expression can occur only after statement?

Comment: Thanks for the help @talex with the base function. Searched for something like it, and was surprised I couldn't find anything.

Expressions are always the last in the block, and there can be 0 or more statements.

Comment: I just search for `m a -> m b -> m a` in hoogle :)

Comment: I did the same on stackage and nothing showed up. Weird.

Comment: Stackage only find it for `Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f a`.

Comment: That would be why then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `sepBy`, this sort of problems often can be solved by `manyTill`, the tricky point is to keep the input that don't be consumed by `manyTill`, it have to use `try $ lookAhead`

> Side note: the reason can be found in source code of `Parsec`.
>   Internally, `manyTill` use `<|>`, so why `try` take effect, and
>   `lookAhead` can retain the input when apply monad bind `>>=`, `>>`

So, the correction look like:

```
parseBlock = between
    (char '{' >> spaces)
    (spaces >> char '}')
    (do
        stmts <- manyTill (parseStmt <* spaces) 
                          (try $ lookAhead (parseExpr >> space))
        parseExpr
    )
```

The above parser just return the output of `parseExpr`, i.e. `5`, if this is your intent, it can be simpified by:

```
manyTill (parseStmt <* spaces) (try $ lookAhead (parseExpr >> space)) >> parseExpr
```

if you actually need the parsed string of statements as well, it become:

```
(do
    stmts <- manyTill (parseStmt <* spaces) 
                      (try $ lookAhead (parseExpr >> space))
    expr  <- parseExpr
    return (concat (stmts ++ [expr]))
)
```

it return `555`

Comment: This worked, but I didn't have to do another change. I have declarations, of the form `[var|let] <ident> ....`. The var and let keywords were being picked up, so I had to save a list of reserved keywords.

Comment: @Herbstein "another change" stand for what ?

Comment: I didn't mention it because I didn't find it super relevant. Since my variable declarations look like `[var|let] <ident> = <expr>` the expression parser used in `manyTill` got caught there already. All I did was making a list of reserved keywords and failed if my parsed expression was in that list.

My actual implementation is here: https://github.com/Herbstein/dusker/blob/master/src/Lib.hs

Comment: @Herbstein Yes, I see

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `sepBy` have certain expectation about its parameters. In case separator successfully parsed it doesn't expect element parser to fail.

To fix that I suggest following improvement

```
parseBlock = between
    (char '{' >> spaces)
    (spaces >> char '}')
    (do
        stmts <- try $ many $ spaces *> parseStmt
        spaces
        parseExpr
    )
```

Comment: That should fail `parseStmt` and when `many` try and fail it should stop. I don't have ghc at hand and can't  check that myself.